# Joomla 3.1 error JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths Unable to create destination

Tags: image, image-processing, joomla, joomla3.1

I installed this plugin (http://www.s2software.it/en/download/joomla-image-resize-cache) and I have this error, this error remains too after creating images/cache folder, on my server are available these: Imagick Shell Execute, JImage (GD) but no one want to work ...

And in System Information every folder, and file is writable, except configuraion.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find 2 temporary resolution:

First: in configuration settings > turn off the display errors

Second: libraries\joomla\filesystem\folder.php > find this: `$obd = ini_get('open_basedir');`

and put in comments like: `//$obd = ini_get('open_basedir');`

Comment: there is no point for turning the display error off,for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a step by step solution that I have found: and it's working very well:

1. Login to Joomla Administartor panel.
2. Go to Global Configuration
3. Click "Server" Tab
4. Change the path from /public_html/tmp to "tmp"
5. Login to control Panel(CPanel) (or you can use an FTP account to access the Joomla files)
6. Open File Manager
7. Open Folder "libraries"
8. Open Folder "joomla"
9. Open Folder "filesystem"
10. Right Click on "folder.php" and click Edit.
11. Look for the line, (search = obd):
    `$obd = ini_get('open_basedir');` Comment out that line with // at the beginning so it becomes:`//$obd = ini_get('open_basedir');`
12. Save and Close.
    And you're down.

**Another solution without any Joomla's core file hacking:**

First find the exact absolute path to your `tmp` folder by using this trick:

Create a PHP file in your website root,for example `path.php`

Place this snippet of code in the file and hit the save button

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "Your Absolute Path is: ";
echo $path;
?>
```

Navigate to `yourdomain.com/path.php` in your browser

From now on:

1. Login to your Joomla Administartor panel.
2. Go to Global Configuration
3. Click no the "Server" tab
4. Change the path to the `"Absolute Path(you've just found)"/tmp`
5. Insert this line of code in your .htaccess file: `php_value open_basedir NULL`

Comment: Great! I was having trouble with this for 2 days, finally a solution.